# Android double click system back button to exit app

Tags: android

In my app I have this code:

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
    
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        showMsgSnack(this.getString(R.string.pressexit));
    
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false, 2000);
    }
```

So if the user clicks the system back button once, it will show a snack message and then after another click on back button it will exit the app.

Currently, the `onBackPressed` is deprecated and I am trying to replace the code to keep the exact same functionality.

The solution I've found needs an onclickListener - which I can't set, because the user will not click any button in app, but the system back button on his device.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
}

    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
         handleOnBackPressed() {
    
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
           showMsgSnack(this.getString(R.string.pressexit));
    
           new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false, 2000);
    
     if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    finish();
        }
    
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the dispatcher in the `onCreate` method of your activity. You can do this like this

```
override fun onCreate() {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            //Your functionality here
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT: Java code

```
getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        //Your logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: it says Cannot resolve symbol 'onBackPressedDispatcher'. I have the code in Java, but still if I use it like this, have error: onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            handleOnBackPressed() {

Comment: Try `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()` instead

Comment: ah sure, this way it is working well, thank you!